# Compact set is closed and bounded - correct idea?

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification

> Prove that a compact set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded.

**My attempt:**
I have already shown that $A$ must be bounded.

To show that $A$ is closed I want to show that  $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ is open.
For that, let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ be arbitrary. Suppose now, for  the sake
of contradiction, that there didn't exists any $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B_{\epsilon}(x) 
\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$. Then we can consider the sequence
$(\epsilon_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. for all $j\in \mathbb{N}$
$\epsilon_{j} >0$  and $\epsilon_{j+1}<\epsilon_{j}$. For each $\epsilon_{j} $ there must
exist some $y_{j} $ s.t. $y_{j} \in A \cap B_{\epsilon_{j} }(x) $. Now I tried to construct an infinite open cover of the points in $Y=\{y_{j}  \mid j\in \mathbb{N}\} $:
$$
\mathcal{O}(Y)=\{(y_{j} -f_{j} , y_{j} +f_{j}  ) \mid j\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and }
f_{j} = \min_{\large y_{k }\in \{y_{i} \  \mid\  i\in \mathbb{N} \}\setminus \{y_{j}\}   }
\left\|y_{j} -y_{k} \right\| \}
.
$$
The reason why I define the cover in such a  weird way is that I want to cover all the $y_j$'s but don't want a finite number of open sets to  overlap in such a way that they cover all $y_j$; however, I'm very unsure whether my attempt in doing this was successful.

Then I want some cover $\mathcal{V}$ which covers  all yet uncovered
points but doens't cover any $y_{j} $. Next, when considering the cover
$$
\mathcal{O}(A) =  \mathcal{O}(Y)\cup \mathcal{V}
.$$
which doesn't have any finite subcover that covers $A$ (because of the $y_j$'s) which contradicts the
fact that $A$ is compact. Is my idea correct (meaning that I can make it rigorous)?

**Note:** $B_{\epsilon}(x) =\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \left\|y-x\right\| <\epsilon\}$

Comment: Hint: use the limit point definition of closed.

Comment: @MarkSaving I don't directly see how this leads to a contradiction. The sequence $(y_i)$ converges to $x$ but $x\not\in A$ so $A$ is not closed since it doesn't contain all its limit points.

Comment: Start by assuming there is a limit point of $A$ which is not an element of $A$. Then use compactness to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Hint if you know the definition of compactness by open covers: take $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A$. For all $y\in A$, there exist $\varepsilon_y>0$ such that $x\in B_{\varepsilon_y}(x)$ and $y\in B_{\varepsilon_y}(y)$ and $B_{\varepsilon_y}(x)\cap B_{\varepsilon_y}(y)=\emptyset$. The collection of all open balls centered at all points $y\in A$ forms an open cover of $A$. Take a finite subcover and conclude.

Comment: Consider that for any point $x\in R^n$ and for any $r > 0$ that $C_r(x)=\{w\in \mathbb R^n| d(x,w) > r\}$.  Note that $\{C_r(x)\}$ is an open cover of $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{x\}$. (Can you prove that?). So if $x\not \in A$ then $A\subset \mathbb R^n\setminus \{x\} \subset \bigcup C_r(x)$.  So $\{C_r(x)\}$ is an open cover of $A$. So there is a finite subcover of $A$.  Can you prove that means both $x$ is *not* a limit point of $A$ and that $A$ is bounded?

Comment: @fleablood could you please tell me what is correct/wrong in my attempt?

Comment: Technically, you need more in your hypothesis to evaluate this proof. All of the suggestions are assuming your space has a metric. Your proof seems to imply that $A\subset\mathbb R^n$ so it is probably okay. Consider a space $X$ where the only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$. Then every subset is compact but none only $X$ and $\emptyset$ are closed.

Comment: @JohnDouma I forgot to mention that $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It's easier to show *directly* that $R^n/A$ is open and find and $\epsilon$ that forces $B_\epsilon(x)\subset R^n/A$. Here's how to do that. Find an open cover of $A$ that is based on how far every point of $A$ is from $x$.  This open cover has a finite cover so use that to realise there is some minimal value so that all point of $A$ are at least that far from $x$.  Let $\epsilon$ be that distance.  Do you need more details.

Comment: @fleablood thanks! I think the idea of my proof is correct in some sense but hard to realise (make rigorous). Your idea is much better and easier to formalise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are putting the $y_i$ close to $x$ *first* and trying to build on open cover on *just* them and not on all the points in $A$.

Find an open cover for *all* $w\in A$ via $B_{r_w}(w)$.  And we can "keep" all these neighborhoods away from $x$ by letting $r_w =\frac 12 d(w,x)$.  That way for all the points $y \in B_{r_w}(w,x)$ we have $d(y,x) > r_w$.

And that's good.  As $\{B_{r_w}(w)\}$ is an open cover and $A$ is compact we have finite subcover $U$.  If we consider the values of the $r_\alpha$ radii of the $B_{r_\alpha}(\alpha)$ sets in the finite subcover, there are a finite number of them so there is a least radius $r$.

Now as all $w \in A$ are in *some* $B_{r_y}(y)$ in the finite subcover (not nesc. centered at $w$) and as $r_y \ge r$ then all $w \in A$ are so that $d(w,x) > r$.

And that's it.... if $\epsilon = r = \min r_\alpha = \min \{r_\alpha|$ indexes of the finite subcover of the $B_{r_\alpha}(\alpha)\}$ then if $d(x, u) < r$ then $u\not \in A$.  So $B_r(x) \subset \mathbb R^n \setminus A$.

So $\mathbb R^n\setminus A$ is open.

.... still not the most straightforward way to go.